# Docker container for program building only without running

Tags: docker, devops

I have a really simple (I think) question. Is it good idea to have docker container which is responsible only for building the project? I want to build a project in one container (container A) and then share the target file and libraries from container A in the docker volume to another container (container B) where I want to use the target file as an argument in the target program (container B). It's a bit hard to describe, so I'll try to explain it more if you need it. Thanks a lot of for help.

Edit:
Ok, I'll try to describe my situation. Container B contains a program for complex calculations (simulations etc.). My goal is to create an application that will receive Dockerfile as input and then I will want to programmatically build an image and run the Docker container (as result I will get built project in container A). Next I want to deliver the output (binaries, class files, libraries etc) to container B from container A to run the simulation (for example: simulation run myfilefromcontainerA). After that, I need to collect the simulation result files and process them in my application at the host level.

Comment: This is a valid use case. You may also be interested in multi-stage builds (https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find more information on the correctness of this use case? Once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: As @Henry commented, you can achieve this with multi-stage build from the build phase of you docker images. Can you please tell us more precisely what you are trying to do? What programing language you're using? We can try to provide you a minimal example from which you can start from...

Comment: I added more information in main post.

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances it's reasonable to have a container of only build tools.  Do *not* put code or binaries in Docker volumes, though; use that build-tools container to build your application and use that as the first stage in a multi-stage build.

Let's say you have a build-tools-only image.  Maybe that looks like:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential \
      ... libfoo-dev ...
# no EXPOSE, USER, CMD, &c.
```

Now you have a local source tree, so you can invoke that image like

```sh
sudo docker run \
  --rm \
  -v "$PWD:$PWD" \
  -w "$PWD" \
  -u $(id -u) \
  my/build-tools \
  ./build-everything.sh
```

This is involved and requires having administrator-equivalent privileges on the system (you can trivially use this invocation to overwrite the host's `/etc/sudoers` file, for example) so I wouldn't recommend this for day-to-day use.  It's valuable in two places:

1. You have a CI system that has a bunch of replicas.  It's easier to install your build tools in an image that the CI system can run and that you can freely update, than it is to update all of the replicas to a newer toolchain.
2. Your build system has a lot of host-level dependencies, and it's important to do local testing against a specific known-good set of versions of these.

If you want to use this as the basis for a later build, you can.  You generally want the result of a build to be a Docker image that you can push and run elsewhere.  Using this in a multi-stage build can look like:

```sh
FROM my/build-tools AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY . ./
RUN ./build-everything.sh

FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update ... # to install runtime dependencies only
COPY --from=build /build/the_app /usr/bin/the_app
CMD ["the_app"]
```